# JSON file name can have more than one period?

Tags: json

Such as bb.king.json — is this still proper?

Details. I have about 2,100 people I want to write out each person as a separate file with their details in json format. I will use their email address up to the "@" because that way they will all be unique file names. We use a first.last@domain.com format. So the resulting file name would be elvis.presley.json as it sits on the file server.

Comment: I don't believe the naming convention of the JSON file itself really matters as long as the content inside of that file is JSON validated.

Comment: Thank you @Anthony. I agree but didn't want to waste any time while coding that part today.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing restricting you in the names of your files is your file system.

See limitations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems?wprov=sfia1).

JSON itself does not care about the name of the file.

That means yes - you can use names like bb.king.json